# Classification accuracy is better with noise added?

Tags: classification, white-noise

I'm making a system to classify 2 class motor-imagery EEG of human brain. I use simple Low Pass Filter to pre-process the data (with or without added noise). I'm using LDA as my classifier.

To test the sensitivity to noise of my system, I added white gaussian noise to the raw signal (I tried with 40dB SNR).
The classifier's accuracy went up after I added the noise (about 1-2% comparing to the non-added noise data). Is it wrong if I assumed the accuracy should be going down if we add noise to the data? So then why the accuracy went up?

I've read a little bit about Stochastic Resonance. Is that what happened?

Thank you in advance.

added : I only classify two classes; X or Y, when in fact the signal contains more than just X and Y. There are unwanted informations spread throughout the signal that I didn't classify, which I think the misclassification (or not, by luck) may occur by putting them to a certain class. Is it wrong if I conclude that the white noise I added attenuate that effect?

Comment: Luck? Did you try again with "new" noise?

Comment: I would say that your first try was overfitting on your data and was bad to generalize. And adding noise forced your model to generalize and find other parameters that fitted your data better.

Comment: Another possibility (or another theme of overfitting): LDA inverts the covariance matrix, which is often numerically difficult. If the data has tight clusters within the covariance matrix may have a bad condition number (it is "practically" not of full rank). In that case, the noise may have spread out the clusters.

Comment: +1 to Thierry, I think it is worth expanding and converting to a full answer... with references to Hastie, Tibshirani and Friedman about overfitting, say :).

Comment: I've tried it again with 20dB SNR, and the accuracy went down, finally. So is it really just luck? I have to agree with the overfitting problem... though I haven't quite grasped the concept yet. Also thank you for pointing out about LDA @cbeleites that helps me a lot :)

Comment: Classification accuracy is an improper scoring rule that is optimized by a bogus model.  The problem is your choice of accuracy scores.

Comment: And by the way, try to not put too many acronyms. It's hard to understand what you are working on/with.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I'm not sure about using classification accuracy either, but I don't know which method I should use to score the system... maybe you can give me some suggestions? :) @ Thierry sorry, I edited and added some details :)

Comment: Much has been written about this.  Briefly it is highly beneficial to use predicted probabilities after validating the calibration accuracy using a high resolution calibration curve estimator, then compute various measures of predictive discrimination such as generalized $R^2$, $c$-index (ROC area), etc.